# Disable "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

When I show some alert consecutive, checkbox "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" appear.
I know it's a browser feature, but i want disable it.
What solution!

Comment: That's not possible. That feature is there to prevent exactly this.

Comment: You can't, and this feature is present in browsers to prevent annoying multiple dialogs from popping on the user's screens.

Comment: You cant change the feature programmatically, but you can change the browsers settings. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=10737317#p10737317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a built-in browser feature you can't change it nor there is an option for this on Chrome. Other browsers may have this option but that is unlikely since this prevents alert spamming. You may also find a browser or an older browser version that may have this feature disabled or not have it at all, though I don't recommend using older browsers.
Also If you don't show alerts with much frequency the checkbox doesn't appear.

The best alternative may be to use a javascript/HTML solution prompting the user with a `<div>` that is above all others, kind of like what *LightBox* does.